# Hyperlink Control: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: vb.net

I have a SQL column with the name of "documents" that hold all the uploaded documents name like this: test1.doc;test2.pdf;test3.pdf. Some records for this column has no data or only has one or two documents. In my FormView I have 3 hyperlinks like this:

```
    **//Hyperlink # 1**
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text='<%# If(Eval("documents") Is DBNull.Value, "No 
    document available", Eval("documents").ToString().Split(";")(0)) %>' NavigateUrl='<%# 
    String.Format("~/documents/uploads/{0}", Eval("documents").ToString().Split(";")(0))  %>' > 
    </asp:HyperLink><br />

**//Hyperlink # 2**
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" Text='<%# If(Eval("documents") Is DBNull.Value, "No 
    document available", Eval("documents").ToString().Split(";")(1)) %>' NavigateUrl='<%# 
    String.Format("~/documents/uploads/{0}", Eval("documents").ToString().Split(";")(1))  %>' > 
   </asp:HyperLink><br />

**//Hyperlink # 3**
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" Text='<%# If(Eval("documents") Is DBNull.Value, "No 
    document available", Eval("adocuments").ToString().Split(";")(2)) %>' NavigateUrl='<%# 
    String.Format("~/documents/uploads/{0}", Eval("documents").ToString().Split(";")(2))  %>'> 
    </asp:HyperLink>
```

When the document column has only 1 document, I'm getting the error message: **Index was outside the bounds of the array** and it points to Hyperlink # 2. But if a record has 3 documents name, it shows all 3 records as expected. I really appreciate any help or guide me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

That is clear because creating an array with `.Split` you aren’t sure about array length.
So passing a parameter to get an element by this array you have to be sure that array contains the element which means you need to be sure the array length is > to index you want to get.
In this case just add a test  for that as the code below shows (`index` is the parameter 0, 1, 2 etc….)

```
<%# If(Eval("documents") Is DBNull.Value OrElse Eval("documents").ToString().Split(";").Length < index, "No document available", Eval("documents").ToString().Split(";")(index)) %>
```

Comment: Hello G3nt, thanks for responding to my question. Do I need to do anything on the NavigateURL property too or only on the Text property?

Comment: Hello @R0m30. Yes, you have to do the same thing :)

Comment: Thank you G3nt_M3caj it’s working now! I appreciate your help.